# check user availability in forms in jsp

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a jsp form which takes in user details. On submit button it goes to a jsp page where the details are entered into the database. But before that I would like to check if the username is available as soon as the user clicks the check availability button. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript and Xml). Its the best web2.0 technology. You can manipulate DOM based on the answer from server

Answer (score 2):

2 ways:

1. Just redisplay the same page after submitting the form wherein you conditionally display the validation message. This is rather trivial and already covered in the Hello World example in [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).
2. Use Ajax to send an asynchronous HTTP request and manipulate the HTML DOM based on the response of the request. This requires a bit more in depth understanding of how websites really work and what JavaScript is. You can find some concrete examples in [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)